# How do I use relative time in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have Rails 1.9.3. I'm trying to use relative time in the Rails library.

I know there's a method `time_ago_in_days` but I don't know where, in which file, to use it and then how to put this format (is it normal %d?) in my Devise translation.

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the documentation for [`time_ago_in_days`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words) and here's a few examples.

```
time_ago_in_words(3.minutes.from_now)                 # => 3 minutes
time_ago_in_words(3.minutes.ago)                      # => 3 minutes
time_ago_in_words(Time.now - 15.hours)                # => about 15 hours
time_ago_in_words(Time.now)                           # => less than a minute
time_ago_in_words(Time.now, include_seconds: true) # => less than 5 seconds

from_time = Time.now - 3.days - 14.minutes - 25.seconds
time_ago_in_words(from_time)      # => 3 days

from_time = (3.days + 14.minutes + 25.seconds).ago
time_ago_in_words(from_time)      # => 3 days
```

This is a view helper, so it is expected to be called in a view context. It's not gonna work in your model or controller by default.

If you need the same feature elsewhere, for example in a custom class in `/lib`, then you may want to check the source code and recreate the feature in your code (you can copy/paste the method, but it's likely you will need a less generic method so you may end up with a much smaller implementation).